# Excel output not matching scraping and not scrolling issues (Windows user)

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

Excel output not matching what it is scraping. It only scrapes some of the data.

I believe the issue is something to do with the below but I can’t seem to get it working no matter what I change.

```
with open('Aperture Science.csv', 'a+', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in zip(langs1_text, langs2_text, langs_text, elem_href):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

I am running a job on this [site](https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/football/today) and as far as I can tell the job runs smoothly and successfully.  I am using windows. Here is the [code](http://textuploader.com/d43ey).

Unfortunately, the output does not match what I see in the console.  The console says I scraped all pages and its fine.
The excel shows just [this](https://ibb.co/m39Rqm)

The other issue is it is not scrolling at all. While not breaking the code, it is odd.   I have also tried:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

To see if it made any difference.